# Proxy between BasicHttpBinding and WsHttpBinding

Tags: c#, php, proxy, basichttpbinding, wshttpbinding

For an important customer, I've to implement a SoapClient in PHP to connect to a .Net webservice setup in WsHttpBinding.

I know PHP SoapClient doesn't support it. So my goal is to develop a proxy software written in C# which will be a 'bridge' between BasicHttpBinding and WsHttpBinding.
So PHP will communicate only with BasicHttpBinding side of the proxy, the proxy will translate the request to the real WS with WsHttpBinding and return to PHP an answer into BasicHttpBinding format.

That's my goal, but I'm just starting in C# ... so I need help to do this.

Is someone can help me or give me advice ?

Thanks,

Comment: WCF can also do a REST interface with XML or JSON formatting. In the past I've found that when attempting to hook up to WCF from non .Net languages, such as Ruby, REST is much easier than SOAP.

Comment: I thought all customers were important. That's main reason some of them still breathing...

Answer (score 1):

You could expose two endpoints in your WCF service:

```
<service name="MyCompany.MyService">
    <endpoint
      address="/advanced"
      binding="wsHttpBinding"
      contract="MyCompany.IMyContract" />
    <endpoint
      address="/simple"
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      contract="MyCompany.IMyContract" />
    <endpoint
      address="mex"
      binding="mexHttpBinding"
      contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
```

Your PHP client will point to `http://mycompany.com/myservice.svc/simple` and other client to `http://mycompany.com/myservice.svc/advanced`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately wsHttpBinding is a constraint imposed on me. I can not ignore or change it.
So the 'proxy' is the only method I found to pass over.